# Getting error while running the project in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm continuously getting the following error while running my android project on titanium.

My Settings:
`Java JDK 1.8`

`Node v8.16.0`

`Win 10 64-Bit`

`Python 3.6`

`Titanium 8.2.0 GA`

`Android SDK 28`

```
[INFO] : Building Java source files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\javac.exe "-J-Xmx3072M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "D:\Android SDK\platforms\android-28\android.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\java_websocket.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\kroll-common.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\titanium.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-multidex.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\WebViewClient.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-appcompat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-animated-vector-drawable.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-annotations.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-core-ui.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-core-utils.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-fragment.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-media-compat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-vector-drawable.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-transition.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-arch-lifecycle-viewmodel.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-arch-lifecycle-livedata-core.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-arch-lifecycle-common.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-arch-core-runtime.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-arch-core-common.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-arch-lifecycle-runtime.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\exifinterface.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-compat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-compat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-design.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-design.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-cardview.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\android-support-v7-cardview.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-utils.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\4.0.4\hyperloop-android.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\4.0.4\lib\dexmaker-1.4.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\4.0.4\lib\dexmaker-dx-1.4.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\kroll-apt.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\8.2.0.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar;R.class;AssetCryptImpl.class;CalorietrackActivity.class;CalorietrackAppInfo.class;CalorietrackApplication.class" "-d" "C:\Users\Muhammad Qaiser\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\CalorieTrack\build\android\bin\classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.7" "-source" "1.7" "@C:\Users\Muhammad Qaiser\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\CalorieTrack\build\android\java-sources.txt"
```

I'm new to titanium, so I'm not able to fix the error.

[image]

Comment: Can you try Node 10.x and Java 1.8.0_131?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, changed JAVA path and JAVA_HOME from environment variables to a 64-bit Java Installation. Before it was set to 32-bit JAVA.

NOTE: You still need 32-bit JAVA for Appcelerator Studio and Titanium SDK to work properly.